# What is passed with the bind in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am binding a select of a custom control to a function.  I just want to clarify when I bind something like this

```
auditFileUpload.bind("select",  uploadSelectfunction);
```

I know I can use the following function

```
uploadSelectfunction(e)
{

}
```

how is e getting passed? is it the events? or the object itself?

if I had a function like this, how would I bind it?

```
uploadSelectfunction(e, datatype)
{

}

auditFileUpload.bind("select",  function() { uploadSelectfunction(events, "CSV"   });
```

I tried events, it doesn't work..

sugesstions? clarifications?

Comment: which version of jQuery do you use?

Comment: jquery version is 1.8.2

Comment: `auditFileUpload.on("select",  function(e) { uploadSelectfunction(e, "CSV") }) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events parameter is simply the first parameter passed to the event handler/method. Just pass that on:

```
auditFileUpload.bind("select",  function(events) { uploadSelectfunction(events, "CSV"
```

In the original version uploadSelectfunction is simply a pointer to a function that happens to take one argument. That events argument is defined inside the select event.

If you put an inline method instead (as you have done) you need to accept the events parameter, and pass it on to your code.